# C# Object Oriented Programming Declaring Properties

Tags: c#, oop, variables, scope

I have a class and in each method I am declaring the following lines repeatedly:

```
var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));
```

How and where do I declare them so that it is available to each method so that I'm not having to write the same line repeatedly inside each method?

```
public class EmailService 
 {
    public EmailService()
    {

    }

    public void NotifyNewComment(int id)
    {
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

        var email = new NotificationEmail
        {
            To = "yourmail@example.com",
            Comment = comment.Text
        };

        email.Send();

    }

     public void NotifyUpdatedComment(int id)
    {
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

        var email = new NotificationEmail
        {
            To = "yourmail@example.com",
            Comment = comment.Text
        };

        email.Send();

    }

  }
```

Comment: Declare them outside of a method but inside a class as public, private, ect. as needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make them class-level members:

```
public class EmailService 
{
    private string viewsPath;
    private ViewEngineCollection engines;

    public EmailService()
    {
        viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));
    }

    public void NotifyNewComment(int id)
    {
        var email = new NotificationEmail
        {
            To = "yourmail@example.com",
            Comment = comment.Text
        };

        email.Send();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

This would populate the variables once when you create a new `EmailService`:

```
new EmailService()
```

Then any method executed on that instance would use the values which were created at that time.

Comment: Just to add (for those who do not know), the assignments in the example above are being done in the constructor.